# Capturing Price Field selection onto Membership record

Tags: price-sets

We've been doing Membership pricing with a straight Membership Type list i.e. without Price Sets, but now want to add an option to receive the quarterly newsletter via snail mail, with a surcharge. I created the Price Set and managed to create the Contribution Page with a checkbox for the newsletter. I need to capture the newsletter option into the Membership, how do I do that? I set the Financial Type as "Publications", maybe that's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what you're suggesting. We already have a (mandatory) radio button with 8 different membership levels. We want to keep that as mandatory and add an option for the newsletter. Are you suggesting a 16-button radio? Or two radio button sets? Or a radio set and a checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your Price Set you need to set them up for Memberships, then when you create eg a Radio button field you should be offered your Membership Types when you add an option to that field.

You should then see these line items on the Contribution record eg

[image]

You should also be able to get these out via Reports such as the ones the [LineReport](https://github.com/Skvare/com.skvare.lineitemreport/issues) extension offer.

Comment: What I did. (1) A mandatory field as a Radio button to select member level varying  from $18 to $250, Financial Type "Member Dues." (2)  optional checkbox to select the newsletter for $9, Financial Type "Publications." (3) optional donation, financial type "Donation". I "joined"  withdollars in each, the total was calculated correctly. But when I do a Find Donations and export Financial Type and Total Amount, the total of the 3 shows as Member Dues. I had hoped for 3 separate amounts with different Financial Types.

Comment: There are extensions for reports that can give you line items such as com.skvare.lineitemreport

Comment: How I do know it is even recorded that way? When I inquire on the individual Donation I still cannot see a breakdown.

Comment: answered in answer - or tried to.